# Text overlaps when maximised or on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have been trying to learn CSS from the book by Jon Duckett. 
I'm learning the concepts of positioning and floats. When I tried to implement them,

```
<head>
    <title>Try</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#container {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        div#cont_2 {
            width: 800px;
            padding: 0px 5px;
            right: 7%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
        }

        p {
            width: 300px;
        }

        p#right {
            float: right;
        }

        p#clear {
            clear: right;
        }

        p#cont_2_p {
            width: 700px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam nobis aliquam nihil quas soluta nemo ad magnam animi! Veritatis, magnam, vero, pariatur ducimus quibusdam ad sint nostrum architecto natus asperiores odio eum doloremque excepturi expedita veniam tenetur esse sapiente est unde molestiae error et dignissimos dolorem? Rem quas eius nesciunt repellat assumenda temporibus cumque aperiam.
        </p>
        <p id="right">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, sint, soluta ab explicabo labore vero placeat porro fugit tempore dolore deleniti libero sit quod reprehenderit.
        </p>
        <p id="clear">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, ullam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="cont_2">
        <p id="cont_2_p">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error, distinctio, asperiores, maxime amet quidem doloribus repudiandae tenetur quod odio laborum at hic nemo eaque! Vero.
        </p>
        <p id="cont_2_p">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, dolorum, tempore, eveniet distinctio repellendus perspiciatis modi enim saepe officia voluptatem recusandae sed voluptas molestias itaque eius ex reiciendis voluptatum consequuntur architecto molestiae quos esse eaque minima minus velit dolore in voluptate qui vel sequi provident?
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

or this: http://jsfiddle.net/7qYYT/

it worked well on 100% zoom on a browser but when I zoomed in, the text on the right overlaps the text on the left. How do I overcome it?

Comment: If this is a code snippet from the book, I recommend you find a different book!

Comment: No!! I tried it on my own.

Comment: Ah, well, in that case... Review the section on selectors.  You are using `id` as if it were `class`.  You can't have multiple elements with the same id. And often times, it's not necessary to use either `class` or `id` as you can specify what you're looking for with fine granularity in other ways. ;)

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question per se, but here is something you might find helpful. http://jsfiddle.net/JtJsC/4/ . I made it do what I /think/ you were going for. could be helpful regardless.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of position `absolute` of `div#cont_2`

> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

```
   div#cont_2 {
     width: 600px;
     padding: 0px 5px;
     float: right;
     right: 7%;
     /*position:absolute;*/
     top: 10px;
    }
```

And here you have set `top:10px` that sets the top of this div from 10px of parent element. That make overlapping of the other contents.

And of-course please used `class` instead of `id` selector in css. If you want to reuse that. As `Id` selector should be unique in the markup.
[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qYYT/1/)

Comment: But I need the content in the `cont_2` beside the content in `container`.

Comment: @Daniel_V for that you can use `display:inline-block` and make sure you have enough space to have both `div` besides of each other. Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/7qYYT/4/

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches:

1. Instead of setting a fixed width with pixels, set a relative width for the two containers using percentages:

   ```
   div#container {
       width: 33.333%;
       height: 400px;
       padding: 5px;
   }

   div#cont_2 {
       width: calc(66.667% - 10px); // taking padding into account, but this won't work IE<=8
       padding: 0 5px;
       right: 7%;
       position: absolute;
       top: 10px;
   }
   ```
2. Use floats instead of positioning (with relative width, again):

   ```
   div#container {
       float: left;
       width: 33.333%;
       height: 400px;
       padding: 5px;
   }

   div#cont_2 {
       float: right;
       width: calc(66.667% - 10px);
       padding: 0 5px;
   }
   ```

There are other less supported methods as well, such as flex-box.

(BTW, don't use `0px`; just use `0`.)